Issues with VS Code set up
I am trying to set up VS Code to use with LaTeX. I have downloaded MacTeX on my laptop and installed the LaTeX workshop extension on VS Code. These programs are up to date.
However, when I try to call the command "Build with recipe" and select "pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex2," absolutely nothing happens. No new file is created. I cannot even seem to manually create a new .tex file from selecting "File" --> "New File."
I have followed a few tutorials on the internet on how to set up/install the software but cannot move on because I do not even see the same things on my screen as them. Everything is blank.
I have attached an image below to show you that I see it is downloaded but cannot access/click on anything. Any help/insight would be greatly appreciated. I have no clue where the issue could be.


Welcome! Are you able to compile a simple .tex file either on the command line or in TeX Shop? (I think TeX Shop is included with MacTeX.)

Can you create a .tex file using finder and open it in VSCode?

When you select File -> New File, there are some options for specific types of files (depending on the extensions that you have installed), but you can create any file you like. So, in order to create a new .tex file, simply give a filename such as test.tex. VSCode will prompt you to save your file. Prefer to save it in a dedicated folder (not one with other files inside) as LaTeX produces other files while creating the pdf.
Then input any TeX code, such as
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}

and compile it in any way you prefer. Most probably, when you save your file, it will be compiled to pdf immediately (sorry if this is not accurate, I have used VSCode for long and have changed some settings). Or press the green arrow at the top right of our window.
And, next time you want to edit your file, prefer to use the File -> Open Folder command of VSCode to open the folder in which you created the file.
